# ASP.Net how to allow searchbots(google) to skip a disclaimer page

Tags: asp.net, httprequest, search-engine-bots

I am creating an ASP.NET website witch forces users to accept a disclaimer. When they accept the disclaimer a cookie and session is set. On each page request a check is fired to see if the session or cookie present.

We want to allowed Google and other Searchbots to index/craw all the pages without accepting the disclaimer.

What is to best way to do this? The only thing that I can think about is a check in the `Request.ServerVariables`, but I am not sure witch values I should look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bypass the check for the session/coockie in case Googlebot is passing by.

So in this check you indeed need to look at ServerVariables. E.g. for Google this would be something like

```
   HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].Contains("Googlebot"))
```

Of course, anyone pretending to be google will now also be able to skip the disclaimer.

I wouldn't call this cloacking - but no guarantees as to wether google likes it or not

Answer (score -1):

you must add meta tags for that, else deny access using web.config meta tags work this way

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex nofollow">
```

specially for google it is

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

also you can try the [URL Removal Request service](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734&from=61062&rd=1)

Comment: this won't work because the entire page will not be visible to the search engines

Comment: @who ever down voted Disclaimer is a separate page right? or a Popup? Without more info how could someone "give working anywhere" solutions

Comment: Its handled server side, before the page is rendered. The question is not exclude the disclaimer page it selve (btw i didnt vote you down)

Comment: @lvo `it's handled in server` and `ASP.NET website witch forces users to accept a disclaimer. When they accept the disclaimer a cookie and session is set` both the explanation seems to contradict. How the user accepts to disclaimer if it isn't shown to them

Comment: the user accepts it, but the google bot should auto accept it/ not be denied access to a page